# Vagrant gives "proxy is invalid" error, but I'm not behind a proxy (Windows 10)

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I couldn't find anyone else wrestling with this issue -- all the proxy questions I found are people trying to do this *with* a proxy.

I'm setting up a Laravel Homestead box. Windows 10, latest versions of Vagrant and VirtualBox.

UPDATE: This seems to be true across other vagrant boxes as well, so now it seems like this is a Vagrant issue and not unique to Homestead.

When I run `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`, I get this error:

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/excon-0.78.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:582:in `setup_proxy': Proxy is invalid (Excon::Error::ProxyParse)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/excon-0.78.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:80:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/excon-0.78.0/lib/excon.rb:142:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/excon-0.78.0/lib/excon.rb:142:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant_cloud-3.0.2/lib/vagrant_cloud/client.rb:61:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/plugins/commands/cloud/client/client.rb:35:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/plugins/commands/cloud/client/client.rb:35:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/plugins/commands/cloud/auth/middleware/add_authentication.rb:34:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/plugins/commands/cloud/auth/middleware/add_authentication.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:149:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:89:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:89:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:525:in `hook'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:82:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:82:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:149:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:89:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:89:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/plugins/commands/box/command/add.rb:78:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/plugins/commands/box/command/root.rb:66:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:67:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:290:in `cli'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/bin/vagrant:205:in `<main>'
```

Similar error is thrown if I run `vagrant halt` on another machine.

The first line of the error message suggests that it's a proxy problem, but I'm not behind a proxy:

```
$ netsh winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

I've tried rebooting and that didn't change anything. Suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: same problem any solutions

Comment: I never figured it out, and actually switched to MAMP instead. Since then, though, I've had intermittent DNS issues with Windows 10 -- some web sites will just stop loading. I correct this issue by flushing the DNS cache using [https://support.pearson.com/getsupport/s/article/Reset-an-Internet-Connection-Flush-DNS](these steps) and it works. Now I wonder if I had done that earlier if Vagrant would have worked again, but I'm not going back to find out at this point!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today:

There are Windows environment variables called "http_proxy" and "https_proxy". In my case they were different from the internet options -> connections proxy.

I solved this by deleting the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy. Then restarted the system.
Afterwards, the executed vagrant from the shell used the correct proxy.pac script and worked as intended.